# How can I write XML in UTF8 instead of UTF8 without a BOM?

Tags: c#, encoding

My tool creates an XML file upon button press; however, it is UTF8 without BOM. How can I ensure it is created in simple UTF8?

My code is:

```
StreamWriter File = new StreamWriter(folderpath.Text + "\\folder\\setup_file.xml");
       File.Write(textboxON.Text);
       File.Close();
```

Comment: Always tag which language you are using also

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/361975/setting-the-default-java-character-encoding

Comment: @ali786 sorry, c# :)

Comment: Avoid using `File` as a variable name - it's also the name of a class in the .NET framework.  You'll more typically see a varaible name like `writer` used for `StreamWriter`s, but `file` would be acceptable too if it makes sense for you here.

Comment: You should never *need* a BOM for UTF-8.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I need because it is a setup file and the system doesnt accept it without BOM...

Comment: "Simple UTF-8" would, if anything, mean no BOM.

Answer (score 2):

To force a specific encoding, simply pass it in as the second argument of your constructor. More information can be found [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/72d9f8d5(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
StreamWriter File = new StreamWriter(folderpath.Text + "\\folder\\setup_file.xml", Encoding.UTF8);
```

You can also pass in your buffer size as the third argument, but I don't think you will have to worry about it in your case.

Comment: unfortunately it throws exception.

Comment: What's the exception?

Comment: @DanField It says "Argument1: cannot convert from "string" to "System.IO.Stream".

Answer (score 0):

True value was needed in:

```
StreamWriter File = new StreamWriter(srcPath.Text + "\\Destination\\setup.xml", true, Encoding.UTF8, 512);
            File.Write(toAdd.Text);
            File.Close();
```